# R tidymodels recipes near zero variance filter for numeric attributes

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

I have troubles to use the step_nzv in R tidymodels recipes to filter out numeric attributes with small variances but continuous values. To me it seems, that the step applies only for nominal values, as it calculates the number of unique values and the ratio of most common to second most common. However I have an attribut which is almost everywhere close to zero, never zero. Do I have to bin first (and discretize with same sized bins would change everything)?
In the code below, I there is a minimal example. I expect that both columns low_variance_num and low_variance_nom are filtered out which doesn't happen:

```
library(tidymodels)

data <- tibble(num = seq(1000),rand = runif(1000)) %>% 
  mutate(low_variance_num = ifelse(num == 1, 1, rand/10000),
         low_variance_nom = ifelse(num == 1, 1, 0))

data
var(data$low_variance_num)
var(data$low_variance_nom)

recipe <- recipe(formula = num ~., data = data) %>% 
  update_role("num", new_role = "label") %>%
  step_nzv(all_predictors(), freq_cut = 995/5, unique_cut = 10) %>% # 5min bis hier
  prep()
summary(recipe)
```

P.S: Is there a way to use recipes without providing a formula? In this case the formula is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, **yes**, there is a way to use recipes without providing a formula. To do that you call `recipe()` with only the data as an argument and then manually update the roles via `update_role()`. This is the recommended approach when the number of variables is very high, as the formula method is memory-inefficient with many variables.

Next, I want to clarify [what we mean in tidymodels by "nominal"](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/recipe.html):

> Nominal variables include both character and factor.

A numeric variable of all 1s and 0s would *not* be a nominal variable in tidymodels (would not be selected by `all_nominal()`, etc).

Next, I want to point out that I don't think `step_nzv()` is going to do what you are hoping here because you are using the term "variance" in a different sense. If you [check out the docs](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_nzv.html), it describes what we mean here by near-zero-variance:

> For example, an example of near-zero variance predictor is one that, for 1000 samples, has two distinct values and 999 of them are a single value.
>
> To be flagged, first, the frequency of the most prevalent value over the second most frequent value (called the "frequency ratio") must be above `freq_cut`. Secondly, the "percent of unique values," the number of unique values divided by the total number of samples (times 100), must also be below `unique_cut`.

The example `low_variance_num` variable you made is not particularly low-variance by the definition used in this step; it has lots of unique values.

For reference, here is a demo of how to build a recipe without the formula:

```r
library(recipes)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'recipes'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step

df <- tibble(num = seq(1000), rand = runif(1000)) %>% 
  mutate(pred1 = ifelse(num == 1, 1, rand/10000),
         pred2 = ifelse(num == 1, 1, 0))

rec <- recipe(df) %>% 
  update_role(num, new_role = "label") %>%
  update_role(rand, pred1, pred2, new_role = "predictor") %>%
  step_nzv(all_predictors())

rec %>% prep() %>% bake(new_data = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 3
#>      num  rand     pred1
#>    <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1 0.842 1        
#>  2     2 0.942 0.0000942
#>  3     3 0.977 0.0000977
#>  4     4 0.595 0.0000595
#>  5     5 0.259 0.0000259
#>  6     6 0.454 0.0000454
#>  7     7 0.550 0.0000550
#>  8     8 0.388 0.0000388
#>  9     9 0.702 0.0000702
#> 10    10 0.481 0.0000481
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The predictor `pred2` was removed because it has so few unique values and they are almost all 0. The predictor `pred1` was not removed because it has **many** unique values. I think if I wanted to do the kind of filtering you are describing, I would do it in data cleaning/preparation, not within a feature engineering recipe in a model pipeline.